# Method Error Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've tried to debug this error, but cannot figure out what is wrong with my code.

I am using the devise gem for users and `current_user` is a devise method

I am trying to add a before action to my documents controller to prevent editing, updating and destroying a document when not the user who has uploaded it.

This is the error: `undefined method 'documents' for nil:NilClass`

The error is reffering to the private method `authorized_user`

This is my controller code:

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_document, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :dislike]
before_action :authorized_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

def index
    if params[:category].blank?
        @documents = Document.all.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc)

        if params[:search]
        @documents = Document.search(params[:search]).order(:cached_votes_up => :desc)
        elsif
        @documents = Document.all.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc)
        end

    else
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @documents = Document.where(category_id: @category_id).order(:cached_votes_up => :desc)
    end
end

def show
end

def new
    @document = current_user.documents.build
end

def create
    @document = current_user.documents.build(documents_params)

    if @document.save
        redirect_to @document
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
    if @document.update(documents_params)
        redirect_to @document
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @document.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end

private 

def documents_params
    params.require(:document).permit(:title, :category_id, :search, :pdf)
end

def find_document
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
end

def authorized_user
    @document = current_user.documents.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to documents_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this Document" if @document.nil?
end
end
```

I'm not sure why i'm getting the undefined method for the documents

Comment: please show us `current_user`

Comment: the `current_user` is a helper method provided by devise which is the gem I use for users so it is created by devise not me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your filters are ran in the order you declared them.

Let's look at them:

```
before_action :authorized_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```

The first filter checks for document permissions, the second one checks that the user is authenticated. Do you see the issue?

You need to swap the them:

```
before_action :authorized_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```

This will guarantee that `authorized_user` is not called if the user is logged out – and voila!

Comment: Ahh how did i not realize this. thanks alot. I will accept when i can in 5 mins